# Hooking a GWT event onto an element in an external iframe

Tags: java, javascript, dom, gwt, event-handling

I am writing a GWT app that involves interacting with an external document in an iframe. As a proof of concept, I am trying to attach a click handler to a button.

The following works in javascript

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("rawJSIFrame");
var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
var body = doc.body;
var button = doc.getElementsByTagName("input").namedItem("submit");
button.onclick = function() {
    alert("Clicked!");
};
```

Trying to do the equivalent in GWT, I did the following:

```
public void addClickHandlerToSubmitButton(String buttonElementName, ClickHandler clickHandler) {
    IFrameElement iframe = IFrameElement.as(frame.getElement());
    Document frameDocument = getIFrameDocument(iframe);
    if (frameDocument != null) {
        Element buttonElement = finder(frameDocument).tag("input").name(buttonElementName).findOne();
        ElementWrapper wrapper = new ElementWrapper(buttonElement);
        HandlerRegistration handlerRegistration = wrapper.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
    }
}

private native Document getIFrameDocument(IFrameElement iframe)/*-{
        return iframe.contentDocument;
}-*/;
```

The following is the ElementWrapper class:

```
public class ElementWrapper extends Widget implements HasClickHandlers {

    public ElementWrapper(Element theElement) {
        setElement(theElement);
    }

    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
    }


}
```

The code to find the button works fine but the actual click event handler is not getting invoked. Has anybody had a similar issue before, and how did you resolve it?

Thanks in advance,

Tin

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hilbrand is right about the problem being that the GWT method `onAttach()` was not called.

I implemented your original solution, adding the following method to `ElementWrapper`:

```
  public void onAttach() {
    super.onAttach();
  }
```

And called added `wrapper.onAttach()` after the `ElementWrapper` is created. Works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you! I knew there had to be a cleaner way :)

Answer (score 4):

I expect the problem is that the GWT method `onAttach()` is not called when you use the wrapping as in your first example. You can try to use the static `wrap` method on the Button widget. Although to use this the `input` must be of type `button`. Or have a look at the implementation of the `wrap` method. Here is the modified code when using the `wrap` method:

```
Element buttonElement = finder(frameDocument).tag("input").name(buttonElementName).findOne();
Button button = Button.wrap(buttonElement);
HandlerRegistration handlerRegistration = button.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

After researching this further, I found that the iframe is irrelevant. The same behaviour doesn't work on a normal button on the host page.

I basically fixed it by using JSNI to replicate part of GWT's event handling mechanism. The following works:

```
Element buttonElement = DOM.getElementById("externalButton");
new CustomElementWrapper(buttonElement).addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        Window.alert("GWT hooked into button");
    }
});
```

Where CustomElementWrapper is:

```
public class CustomElementWrapper extends Widget implements HasClickHandlers {
    private ClickEventManager clickEventManager;

    public CustomElementWrapper(Element theElement) {
        setElement(theElement);
        clickEventManager = new ClickEventManager(theElement);
    }

    public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
        //The 'right' way of doing this would be the code below. However, this doesn't work
        // A bug in GWT?
        //      
        //              return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
        return clickEventManager.registerClickHandler(handler);
    }


    void invokeClickHandler() {
        clickEventManager.invokeClickHandler();
    }

    public boolean isClickHandlerRegistered() {
        return clickEventManager.isClickHandlerRegistered();
    }
}
```

Finally, the ClickEventManager, where the actual work happens is:

```
public class ClickEventManager {
private boolean clickHandlerRegistered = false;
private ClickHandler clickHandler;
private Element element;

public ClickEventManager(Element element) {
    this.element = element;
}

public void invokeClickHandler() {
    //This shouldn't really be null but we are bypassing GWT's native event mechanism
    //so we can't create an event
    clickHandler.onClick(null);
}

public boolean isClickHandlerRegistered() {
    return clickHandlerRegistered;
}

HandlerRegistration registerClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
    clickHandler = handler;

    if (!clickHandlerRegistered) {
        registerClickHandlerInJS(element);
        clickHandlerRegistered = true;
    }
    return new HandlerRegistration() {
        public void removeHandler() {
            //For now, we don't support the removal of handlers
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
    };
}
private native void registerClickHandlerInJS(Element element)/*-{
    element.__clickManager = this;
    element.onclick 
        = function() {
            var cm = this.__clickManager; 
            cm.@com.talktactics.agent2.client.widgets.ClickEventManager::invokeClickHandler()();
        }
}-*/;
}
```

Personally, I hate this solution because I appear to be duplicating GWT's event handling and quite possibly introducing nasty javascript memory leaks. Any ideas on why my first post doesn't work (remembering that the iframe aspect is a red herring), would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Tin

Comment: Thank you, thank you!  This was exactly what I needed to get it to work in IE7!

Answer (score 1):

You may find this helpful:

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.HasClickHandlers;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.AbsolutePanel;

public class DirectPanel extends AbsolutePanel implements HasClickHandlers {
        public DirectPanel(Element elem) {
                super(elem.<com.google.gwt.user.client.Element> cast());
                onAttach();
        }

        @Override
        public HandlerRegistration addClickHandler(ClickHandler handler) {
                return addDomHandler(handler, ClickEvent.getType());
        }
}
```

You will then be able to make arbitrary containers into widget containers:

```
  Element root = Document.get().getElementById("target");
  DirectPanel p = new DirectPanel(root);
  Button register = new Button("Register");
  register.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      // ...
    }
  });
  p.add(register);
```

And bind events to arbitrary elements:

```
  Element root = Document.get().getElementById("target");
  DirectPanel p = new DirectPanel(root);
  p.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      // ...
    }
  });
```

Specifically in your case, try this:

```
IFrameElement frm = Document.get().createIFrameElement();
Document d = frm.getContentDocument();
NodeList<Element> inputs = d.getElementsByTagName("input");
InputElement target = null;
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.getLength(); ++i) {
  Element e = inputs.getItem(0);
  if (e.getNodeName().equals("submit")) {
    target = InputElement.as(e);
    break;
  }
}
if (target != null) {
  DirectPanel p = new DirectPanel(target);
  p.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  });
}
```

It's always mystified me that GWT makes doing this so difficult and poorly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using iframes i suggest you simply make a http request from GWT via  com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder. Like so:

```
private void getHtml(String url) {
        RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

        rb.setCallback(new RequestCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel(response.getText());

                // Now you have a widget with the requested page
                // thus you may do whatever you want with it.
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                Log.error("error " + exception);
            }
        });

        try {
            rb.send();
        } catch (RequestException e) {
          Log.error("error " + e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSNI to reuse your JavaScript piece of code. Your javascript code would call a gwt method on an object that would throw it on behalf of the button in the iframe.

As to why GWT code does not work -- I guess that is because they use some layer on top of regular browser events that probably cannot span more than 1 frame. That's just a guess though. You could file this as a feature/bug request agains GWT team. If I am right your code looks just fine.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the reply. I guess I'll explore the JSNI path, though I want to stay away from writing custom javascript as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my previous answer. A slight modification to your original solution will make it work.